# Get-MgUserCalendar only works if I have delegate permissions in O365

Tags: powershell, outlook, calendar, office365, powershell-7.0

When calling Get-MgUserCalendar I get an error "The specified object was not found in the store." unless I have given myself delegate permissions on that person's mailbox. I am a global admin in O365. The purpose of my script is to forcibly add an event to user calendars as a reminder to do something.

I expect that the reason I can't simply have access to calendar IDs is due to security risk. Is there a way around this or a better way to get their calendarId?

Comment: You can use an app registration with application level permissions for `Calendars.Read`, which grants access to all calendars

Comment: I'm running `Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Calendars.ReadWrite` and I have consented on behalf of my organization, but I still get the same error. I would have assumed that would work the same way as creating an Azure app as there is a "Microsoft Graph PowerShell" Enterprise application in my Azure instance. Admittedly I am not too well versed in Azure though.